# instead of entering an ip each time how to read a file directly with a list of ip?

Tags: python, ip

```
import httplib


HOST = "192.168.1.1"
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
conn.request("GET","/example`")
res = conn.getresponse()
print res.status, res.reason
```

instead of entering an ip each time how to read a file directly with a list of ip?
thanks

Comment: How does your file look like?\

Comment: Open it and read the lines in it. What is your specific issue with this task?

Comment: I just want to import a file with a list of ip's instead of changing it every time.

Comment: HOST = open("datas.txt", "r")       don't work

Comment: You open a file and create a file object. Now you must tell the file object to read the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as list_of_ips:   
    host_list = list_of_ips.readlines()

for HOST in host_list:
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
    conn.request("GET","/example`")
    res = conn.getresponse()
    print res.status, res.reason
```

with a list like this in `file.txt`:

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nas.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 748, in __init__
    self._validate_host(self.host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1043, in _validate_host
    raise InvalidURL(msg)
httplib.InvalidURL: URL can't contain`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my code :

```
import httplib

with open('datas.txt', "r") as list_of_ips:   
     host_list = list_of_ips.readlines()
for HOST in host_list:
     conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
     conn.request("GET","/example")
     res = conn.getresponse()
     print res.status, res.reason
```

and result :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nas.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 748, in __init__
    self._validate_host(self.host)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1043, in _validate_host
    raise InvalidURL(msg)
httplib.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '91.68.62.77\n' (found at least '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

i found

```
import httplib

with open('datas.txt', "r") as list_of_ips:   
     host_list = list_of_ips.readlines()
for HOST in host_list:
     HOST = HOST.rstrip("\n")
     conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(HOST)
     conn.request("GET","/example`")
     res = conn.getresponse()
     print res.status, res.reason
```